# What is the correct return type of a function returning an iterator produced with a closure borrowing self

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

Consider the following code with an emphasis on `children_iter()`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

type NodeMap = HashMap<i32, Node>;

struct Node {
    id: i32,
    parent: Option<i32>,
    sibling: Option<i32>,
    children: Vec<i32>,
    content: String,
}

pub struct NodeIterator<'a> {
    nodes: &'a NodeMap,
    current: &'a Node,
}

impl<'a> NodeIterator<'a> {
    fn new(node: &'a Node, nodes: &'a NodeMap) -> NodeIterator<'a> {
        NodeIterator {
            nodes,
            current: node,
        }
    }

    pub fn children_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = NodeIterator> {
        self.current
            .children
            .iter()
            .map(|i| self.nodes.get(i).unwrap())
            .map(|n| Self::new(n, self.nodes))
    }
}
```

The compilation of this code fails with:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:30:18
   |
30 |             .map(|i| self.nodes.get(i).unwrap())
   |                  ^^^ ---- `self` is borrowed here
   |                  |
   |                  may outlive borrowed value `self`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:26:36
   |
26 |     pub fn children_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = NodeIterator> {
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
30 |             .map(move |i| self.nodes.get(i).unwrap())
   |                  ^^^^^^^^

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:31:18
   |
31 |             .map(|n| Self::new(n, self.nodes))
   |                  ^^^              ---- `self` is borrowed here
   |                  |
   |                  may outlive borrowed value `self`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:26:36
   |
26 |     pub fn children_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = NodeIterator> {
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
31 |             .map(move |n| Self::new(n, self.nodes))
   |                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to correctly specify lifetimes so that it is clear that the returned iterators are only valid for the lifetime of the current `NodeIterator`?

Comment: `-> impl Iterator<Item = NodeIterator>` doesn't make sense did you mean to write `-> impl Iterator<Item = Node>` instead?

Comment: I don't think so. I want the returned iterator to produce `NodeIterator` values, not `Node` so that I keep recursing down the tree with further calls to `children_iter()` on each produced value. Maybe what is confusing is that NodeIterator has an additional function for accessing `content` of `Node`, but I took that out because I thought it wasn't relevant. Do you mind explaining why it doesn't make sense? Maybe I thought of this wrong.

Comment: An iterator that returns iterators is a bit unusual, but I guess if it works then it works. The more common and standard approach would be to write a single iterator that iterates over the entire data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because in Rust iterators are *lazily-evaluated*. It looks like your closures will execute within the `children_iter` function but they actually don't get executed until the caller calls the `next` method on the returned iterator.

The compiler suggests using the `move` keyword to move the borrowed reference into the closure which fixes the problem. However, you could also fix the problem by *eagerly-evaluating* your iterator and collecting the results in a `Vec<NodeIterator>`. Here's both approaches in a fixed and compiling example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

type NodeMap = HashMap<i32, Node>;

struct Node {
    id: i32,
    parent: Option<i32>,
    sibling: Option<i32>,
    children: Vec<i32>,
    content: String,
}

pub struct NodeIterator<'a> {
    nodes: &'a NodeMap,
    current: &'a Node,
}

impl<'a> NodeIterator<'a> {
    fn new(node: &'a Node, nodes: &'a NodeMap) -> NodeIterator<'a> {
        NodeIterator {
            nodes,
            current: node,
        }
    }

    pub fn children_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = NodeIterator> {
        self.current
            .children
            .iter()
            // lazily-evaluted closures
            // they run in the caller's scope
            .map(move |i| self.nodes.get(i).unwrap())
            .map(move |n| Self::new(n, self.nodes))
    }
    
    pub fn children_iter_vec(&self) -> Vec<NodeIterator> {
        self.current
            .children
            .iter()
            // eagerly-evaluted closures
            // we run them in the current scope
            .map(|i| self.nodes.get(i).unwrap())
            .map(|n| Self::new(n, self.nodes))
            .collect()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2d1a2539fb0f1e520097aa2baf6afa4)